# Fix array of incomplete links

Tags: shell-script

I'm writing a bash script that will find links in a page. It downloads the source code from a page and finds links in *a* tags and stores them into an array, ***$links.*** The problem though is that some links will not include the entire URL, just the sub-page or file. Say the source code of a page looks like this:

```
<h1>Julian's crappy webpage</h1>
<a href="http://one.com">Page One</a>
<a href="https://two.com">Page Two</a>
<a href="/three">Page Three</a>
<a href="four">Page Four</a>
```

After finding links, the array would look something like this:

```
http://one.com
https://two.com
/three
four
```

I also have a variable ***$URL*** which is a valid URL, e.g. "https://google.com"

I need a way to make all of the items in ***$links*** valid by doing different things based on the item. For every item in ***$links***:

- If the item starts with a /, then combine: ***$URL*** + ***${links[n]}***
- If the item does not start with a "/" or "https://" or "http://", then combine: ***$URL*** + ***"/"*** + ***${links[n]}***

Expected response for example above:

```
http://one.com
https://two.com
https://google.com/three
https://google.com/four
```

Comment: to closer: It looks like a plain question to me, bash scripting is ok in U&L.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample script which you can use to implement this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
readonly URL="https://google.com"
links=($(grep -o -P '(?<=href=").*(?=")' source.html)) # read into array

for ((i=0; i<${#links[@]}; i++))
do
  case ${links[$i]} in
    http*)
      : # do nothing
      ;;
    /*)  
      links[$i]="$URL"${links[$i]}; # update array
      ;; 
    *)
      links[$i]="$URL/"${links[$i]}; # update array
      ;;
  esac
done
```

It assumes `source.html` is the downloaded source of the web page in the current directory.

Comment: If prints the correct values to the terminal, but the original array is unaffected.

Comment: @JulianLachniet Check the updated answer.

Comment: I think you still need http: and https: to be separate, because what you have right now would be problematic for `<a href="http">`

Comment: How do you mean? `http*` would match both http and https.

Comment: It does, but it matches false positives, as in my example above.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow! Could you explain more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40461/discussion-between-coffemug-and-julian-lachniet).

Answer (score 0):

There are countless ways that using a regex to parse HTML can [go wrong](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).  Even for a seemingly simple task like extraction of URLs from a HTML file.

So, don't use a regex.  Use something like this instead:

```
#! /bin/bash

htmlfile='./file.html'
URL='https://google.com'

links=($(lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers -force_html "$htmlfile" | 
         sed -e "s=^file://=$URL="))

printf "%s\n" "${links[@]}"
```

This requires that [lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/) be installed.  `lynx` is an ncurses-based text-mode web browser.  It is being used here to just generate a list of links in the HTML file, because `lynx` has already solved the *much harder than you might think* problem of how to reliably find URLs in HTML content (that's an important part of a browser's job).  Other languages like `perl` or `python` have good library modules for parsing HTML to extract URLs.  For shell scripts, use `lynx`.

See `man lynx` for details.

`lynx` is almost certainly available pre-packaged for your Linux distro or other unix-like OS.  If not, you can get the source code from the link above.

Comment: I'm only trying to pull URLs from inside <a> tags, and my regex still works fine. It counts a few things as URLs that aren't, but it's very minimal.

Comment: From the link I posted:  "But, it works!" 
"It's easy!" 
"It's quick!" 
"It will do the job just fine!".  Everyone says that about parsing html with regex.  And they're right.  Until they're not.  Until they run into something their regex doesn't handle.  Until they encounter some of the truly awful abominations of alleged HTML out there in the wild.  And then they're wrong.  Very wrong.

Comment: BTW, try my lynx-based script.  Unlike your regex, it will **not** "... count a few things as URLs that aren't ...".  Not a single one.  It will find every link, with no false positives or false negatives.